# How would I parse the following JSON string using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, json, salesforce, restsharp

I am writing a C# wrapper for the SalesforceIQ platform and I'm having trouble figuring out the best way (or any way) to parse the following JSON string in C# - specifically the `fieldValues` property, which the API specifies as:

> A collection of Field definitions that are associated with the List.
>   These Fields are stored as an array of Field objects, with each Field
>   a mapping of an id, display name, and (in the case of pick list
>   fields) an array of listOptions. The Field’s id is a string containing
>   the index of that field in the order they were created; these ids are
>   used to map fields to their values within List Items. The listOptions
>   property maps to an array of option objects, each containing an option
>   id and the display value of that option. When setting the value of
>   these types of fields, these list fields need to be set to this ID
>   rather than their display value.

My question is - what classes/object structure can I use in C# to model this `fieldValues` data?

```
{
  "id": "<masked>",
  "listId": "<masked>",
  "version": 1,
  "createdDate": 1470089225761,
  "modifiedDate": 1470095205436,
  "name": "<masked>",
  "accountId": "<masked>",
  "contactIds": [
    "<masked>"
  ],
  "fieldValues": {
    "0": [
      {
        "raw": "2"
      }
    ],
    "1": [
      {
        "raw": "<masked>"
      }
    ],
    "4": [
      {
        "raw": "35"
      }
    ],
    "process_close_date": [
      {
        "raw": "<masked>"
      }
    ],
    "process_created_date": [
      {
        "raw": "<masked>"
      }
    ]
  },
  "linkedItemIds": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Field>> fieldValues;
```

where

```
public class Field 
{
    public string raw { get; set; }
}
```